# Using Amazon AWS Lambda Function Serverless Image Handler Resizer function template results in No S3 Access

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-serverless

This is exactly what I did.

I have a S3 Bucket and the image in the S3 bucket is completely public. You can paste the URL directly into any browser and it displays the image. CORS is set to allow all origins.

I followed the AWS tutorial and clicked launch stack to launch default template for serverless image handling.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/deployment.html#step1

While creating the stack is asks you to enter parameters. It asks the source bucket. I entered the SOURCE_BUCKET name exactly! I even double checked. So there I entered the bucket name. It is a public image in that bucket too. Now this is the link right? I am using a default template, it asks for bucket name, I enter it correctly, and then exactly try and use the resizer and it can't find the key.

When I type in the cloudfront URL and the key I get:

{"status":500,"code":"NoSuchKey","message":"The specified key does not exist."}

I have no idea what else do to! The image is completely PUBLIC! I am certain I am typing in the key and URL correctly, I have gotten this to work before but something changed all of a sudden. So I deleted the entire stack before and creating it from scratch and now it is not even making a connection with the key!

What do I do? What other permissions do I need to turn on? And why when creating the stack do they not set this up for you?

UPDATE

So I found out if I add an image to the root of the bucket, it works! But if they key is a path in a subfolder, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Keys are not the same as path in S3. if you are going to stick all your images into a S3 psuedo folder call it images and make sure it is part of the permissions granted to the Lambda function. Just because something is public does not mean Lambda will be able to access it.